# Take Row from Table1 and create or update Column from Table2

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I'd like to make a table with row entries that define columns in another Table. This way I can easily update the tables later on if the questions for a form are changed or added.

Eg.

Table1: Questions

```
Question            column_name     column_type   characters    default
What is your name?      name           Char         255           ''
When where you born?    birth          char         255           ''
What is today's date?   date           int                        ''
Do you have a pet?      pet            bin                        0
```

Table2: Results

```
name        birth       date
Cammy      Teaneck      1988
Tommy      Tenefly      2001
Tasha      Brooklyn     1950
```

In the php form, check to see if all columns exist, if not create them in table2 and then add entry

```
$collect = db_query("SELECT column_name FROM {Table1}");
while ($data = db_fetch_array($collect)){

$name = $data['column_name'];
$stretch = db_query("SELECT $name FROM {Table2}");
if ($stretch == null or false){

UPDATE TABLE Table2 ($name   $type($char) DEFAULT $default)
 }
}
```

Comment: I'd like a binary pet! :-)

Comment: Clearly the data is duplicated in the above tables. How about having a "Question" column in the Results table? How many questions do you have?

Comment: I have like 63+ questions in the actual thing

Comment: how is the data duplicated?

Comment: `DESCRIBE Table2` will give data for each column. Select all the rows in `Table1` and check `column_name` against `Field`. If not present run `ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD #column_name# #column_type#( #characters# ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#default#'` replacing #xxx# with entries in table. You will need to change the column_type to valid column types though.

Comment: int(255) that's some scope for a timestamp LOL

Comment: heh, D:  Well, this was a fake example. thx

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode for what you are asking for is as follows:

```
foreach column in table1 {
  $res = query("select column from table2");
  if( ! $res ) {
    query("alter table add field datatype(size) to table 2");
  }
}
```

Heres a crude implementation, from where I got the idea from:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/193330-alter-table-add-column-if-not-exists-possible/

Answer (score 0):

Please use information schema in mysql to check
whether this table contain this field or not
you can Find table name in  information_schema this 
use Like this

```
SELECT * FROM  information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table2' and COLUMN_name IN ('name','birth','date')
```

Please try this